# visual studio code's marketplace blocked

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code's (VSC) marketplace (for extensions) appears to be blocked, but no proxy server is listed:

```
PS > netsh winhttp show proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).
```

Internet Explorer's LAN settings do not contain proxy settings.

Access to the website (marketplace.visualstudio.com) can be reached by IE and Chrome.

The extensions are available in VSC on another machine, which is connected to the 'net via a guest network.

Is this a proxy-server issue?  An authentication issue?  How do I configure VSC to work in this environment?

Comment: Are you an administrator with the required permission to unblock the marketplace?

Comment: No, I'm not an administrator, nor do I have local-administrative rights.

Comment: Sounds like its been blocked on purpose.  Talk to your Network Administrator about the problem.  The PC that is working, is connected to a different access point, which means realistically it has different rules applied to it.

Comment: Why I can I access in Chrome, but not via VSC?

Comment: You should ask your IT Administrator that question.